# Unity Directional light update (day-night effect)

Tags: unity-game-engine, delay, wait, yield, light

i'm writing here cause i really need your help. i've created this script linked on a gameObject light (Directional).

```
var time : int= 0;

function Update () {
    time+=1;
    transform.Rotate(time*Time.deltaTime, 0 ,0);
        yield WaitForSeconds(0.2);
    if (time == 360){
        time = 0;
    }
}
```

when i start the game, the object don't rotate and if i remove the line:

```
   yield WaitForSeconds(0.2);
```

the rotation starts slowly then increses its speed until (every 2 rounds) it returns to 0.

Comment: So what's the question?  That you don't know why rotation doesn't work when `yield ...` is in the code or that you don't know why the object slowly increases in speed?  The second part is easy, Rotate is a relative function meaning each call appends the input value to the current rotation.  Just do `transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime *speed,0,0)` and you should be fine.

Comment: there are 2 question:

first: why when i add yield nothing happen?

second: why, if i remove yield, the speed of rotation is incresed?
(i wanna increse the rotation, not the speed of rotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jerdak is right. `Update()` is called every frame, and not every second. That way, `time` reaches 360 very fast. In order to get the elapsed time since last call to `Update`, use `Time.deltaTime`. Which basically means when you do `transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime * speed, 0, 0);`, it'll rotate according to your speed. So use a speed measure rather than a time measure.

> the rotation starts slowly then increses its speed until (every 2
>   rounds) it returns to 0.

This is expected behaviour. Like I said, you used `time` instead of `speed`. You increase the speed (named: `time`) every 0.2 seconds, thus increasing the rotation speed.

> when i start the game, the object don't rotate

I am unsure why this happens but when you wait long enough, you'll see the rotation occuring anyway. It might be happening but very slowly.